# Selector invoked from objective-c on a managed object that has been GC'ed, how to avoid viewcontrollers from being GC'd

Tags: xamarin.ios

We have an app in the appstore that works without any issues on iPhone 4g/4gs but when I tested it on an iPod I got a surprise because it crashes all the time at "random" places. Looking at the strack traces it seems my viewcontrollers have been GC'ed.

Will the viewcontroller be garbagecollected if I write methods like this:

```
public void PushShowTeamController (Object a)
{
  var teamController = new TeamController (a);
  NavigationController.PushViewController (teamController, true);
}
```

Because the iPod suddently throws an error like this:

```
 Jan  6 18:52:09 unknown MyApp[5197] <Warning>: Received memory warning.
 Jan  6 18:52:10 unknown UIKitApplication:mypackage.app[0x9db2][5197] <Notice>: Unhandled Exception: System.Exception: Selector invoked from objective-c on a managed object that has been GC'ed ---> System.MissingMethodException: No constructor found for MyApp.TeamController::.ctor(System.IntPtr)
 Jan  6 18:52:10 unknown UIKitApplication:mypackage.app[0x9db2][5197] <Notice>:   at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] args, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, System.Object[] activationAttributes) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
 Jan  6 18:52:10 unknown UIKitApplication:mypackage.app[0x9db2][5197] <Notice>:   at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type, System.Object[] args, System.Object[] activationAttributes) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
 Jan  6 18:52:10 unknown UIKitApplication:mypackage.app[0x9db2][5197] <Notice>:   at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type, System.Object[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
 Jan  6 18:52:10 unknown UIKitApplication:mypackage.app[0x9db2][5197] <Notice>:   at MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Runtime.ConstructNSObject (IntPtr ptr, IntPtr klass) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
 Jan  6 18:52:10 unknown UIKitApplication:mypackage.app[0x9db2][5197] <Notice>:   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

---

This will happen when an *managed* object is disposed (when no reference is left to an instance) and the object is later *resurfaced* by *native* code.

You need to ensure that a reference to `MyApp.TeamController` is kept in managed code as long as it can be required (e.g. accessed) by native code.

In most case MonoTouch will ensure a reference is kept. Your code:

```
NavigationController.PushViewController (teamController, true);
```

is correct and `UINavigationController` will keep a reference to your `teamController`. However if you call `PushViewController` on another controller then the first reference will be overwritten and will be collectable by the garbage collector (GC). This situation would lead to the exception you are seeing.

Note: because you can't predict when the GC will collect unreferenced object instance the exception will appear to be thrown randomly.

Comment: Any way to force the GC to collect memory to track these down locally? My 4gs device has too much memory :-) Or must I write some dummy code that allocates a whole lot of memory to track them down?

Comment: When debugging on the iOS simulator MonoTouch starts a thread that calls `GC.Collect` very often to **help** (not guarantee) spot such issues. This is what's been known as **the GC is more aggressive** since MonoTouch 4.

Comment: ok, never seen them myself but I keep getting crash logs from users (3-4 a day with 1000 DLs a day) so I guess it's mostly from "old" devices like 3GS with less memory. Well, I'll try digging deeper. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience this happens when i use a lot of dispose() on managed objects instead of setting them to null and leaving the GC to do its job. Also anonymous delegates combined with dispose() can lead to such problems

Comment: Not using dispose, but changing the view controller variable to an instance variable of the controller who does the pushing seems to help. Maybe that's the correct way of pushing new view controllers? That you need a reference to them?